# Creating a simple retry function in Rust with no predefined types involved

Tags: rust

I'm totally new to Rust and I'm coming from Golang.

I'm trying to translate this simple Golang function to Rust:

```golang
func Retry(attempts int, seconds int, f func() error) (err error) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        err = f()
        if err == nil {
            return nil
        }

        if i > 0 {
            println("retried")
        }

        if i >= (attempts - 1) {
            break
        }

        time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
    }

  return fmt.Errorf("error after %v attempts", attempts)
}
```

This function is to call like this:

```golang
if err := Retry(3, 5, func() error { // this is an immediate function that calls the other one
  err := maybeErroringFunction()
  return err
}); err != nil {
  println("it doesn't respond after all retries")
}
```

In Rust I'm trying with the below code, but I'm very disappointed and hungry for notions to make it better by finally learning this beautiful language:

```rust
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

pub async fn retry(attempts: u8, delay: u64, f: fn() -> Result<(), ()>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    for n in 1..attempts {
        if n > 1 {
            println!("retried {} times", n);
        }

        match f() {
            Ok(()) => break, // this is wrong here because I should return Ok!
            Err(()) => thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(delay)),
        }
    }

    println!("error after {} attempts", attempts);

    Err(())
}
```

but if I try to use this function I don't even know how to call it, example:

```rust
use hyper::{client::Client, Body, Request};

pub async fn trying_it() {
    let hyper_client = Client::new();

    let req = Request::builder().uri("http://localhost").body(Body::empty()).unwrap();

    // I need to retry this call:
    // let resp = hyper_client.request(req).await.unwrap();

    let resp = retry(3, 2, hyper_client.request(req).await.unwrap());

    println!("{:?}", resp);
}
```

but the error is:

```
mismatched types
expected fn pointer `fn() -> std::result::Result<(), ()>`
       found struct `hyper::Response<hyper::Body>` rustc E0308

main.rs(26, 16): arguments to this function are incorrect
```

Should/can I use closures?

What else?

Comment: "Should/can I use closures? What else?" Futures. `hyper_client.request(req)` is a function which returns a `Future`, the `Future` is polled through `await` but that necessarily infects the caller. That also means you need to use an async-aware sleep.

Comment: Can you please write an example please?

Comment: You need to pass a closure (it is like a lambda). As is you call a function and pass the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in the comment, you're trying to retry an async call, this means your retrier needs to be async-aware, it needs to take in an async "thing".

And yes you need closures as well: futures are "one-shot", once done they're done, regardless of success or failure.

And since you're in an async context you should use an async sleep (I used Tokio's) otherwise sleeping will lock up the scheduler.

```rust
pub async fn retry<F, Fu>(attempts: u8, delay: u64, f: F) -> Result<(), ()>
where F: Fn() -> Fu,
      Fu: Future<Output=Result<(), ()>>{
    for n in 0..attempts {
        if n >= 1 {
            println!("retried {} times", n);
        }

        if let Ok(()) = f().await {
            return Ok(());
        }
        
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(delay)).await;
    }

    println!("error after {} attempts", attempts);

    Err(())
}
```

That means on the caller side you need an async closure, which are not stable, so you need a closure with an async block. And since hyper's requests are (apparently) not clonable, you need to create the request inside the closure / block:

```rust
pub async fn trying_it() {
    let hyper_client = Client::new();

    let resp = retry(3, 2, || async {
        let req = Request::builder().uri("http://localhost").body(Body::empty()).unwrap();
        hyper_client.request(req).await.map_err(|_| ())?;
        Ok(())
    }).await;

    println!("{:?}", resp);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9dded3ff61ff7c409d95615e25e262a

With a bit of rejiggering, you can also make the retrier return whatever the retried call returns: the value in case of success, or the last failure.

This actually makes the calling easier since you don't need to muck around with transforming the result, though it makes the `retry` a bit icky<sup>1</sup>:

```rust
pub async fn retry<F, Fu, V, E>(mut attempts: u8, delay: u64, f: F) -> Result<V, E>
where F: Fn() -> Fu,
      Fu: Future<Output=Result<V, E>> {
    
    loop {
        match f().await {
            Ok(v) => return Ok(v),
            Err(e) if attempts == 1 => return Err(e),
            _ => {
                attempts -= 1;
                sleep(Duration::from_secs(delay)).await;
            }
        };
    }
}

pub async fn trying_it() {
    let hyper_client = Client::new();

    let resp = retry(3, 2, || async {
        let req = Request::builder().uri("http://localhost").body(Body::empty()).unwrap();
        hyper_client.request(req).await
    }).await;

    println!("{:?}", resp);
}
```

---

1: I would assume there are better solutions using streams and `try_fold` but I've not used streams much.

Comment: I'm studying your answer as if it were pure gold.

Comment: Your second version may crash is `attemps == 0` and it fails the first time.

Comment: @BlackBeans is there a way to make it invalid to use `0` as parameter? A type only > 0? Is it possible?

Comment: @FredHors Yes, it is possible, but I'm not sure it's absolutely necessary here. If you're interested in how to do that, you should have a look at [NonNull](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html), which is a non-null pointer. Alternatively, you could change the meaning of that argument: instead of being the number of attempts, it could be the number of retries (because you know you will always want to try at least once). Or you can just be satisfied with it not handling that case, because you know people will never call it with `0` as argument (not pretty, but reasonable).

Comment: you could use [NonZeroU8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroU8.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! What a community!

Comment: just need a tiny bit of refactor, what I came up with: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b8c502a4fd475cf863527d24b51f350)